# How do you update a hashed password with php and pdo

Tags: php, database, pdo, twitter-bootstrap-3, developer-tools

Last months I make a forum for a school project, but I want that an user can change his own password. How can you update a password with PHP and PDO.

I thought you can use:

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password']; 

if($password == $confirm_password){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE password SET password = 
    'password_hash($password)' WHERE id=$id");
} else {
     .....
}
```

But it didn't what I wanted...

And I have a form but I can't show that, because something went wrong.
I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: `$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE password SET password '".password_hash($password)."'' WHERE id=$id");` You have syntax error

Comment: In the code you posted you only seem to be preparing a statement. Are you actually saving it to the database too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you do is write the new password to the database after hashing it of course

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password']; 

if($password == $confirm_password){

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE password SET password = :pwd WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->execute([':pwd' => password_hash($password), ':id'=> $id]);
} else {
     .....
}
```

> Your script was wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 3):

What you are using here is called a [cargo cult prepared statement](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement) and it gives you no protection from SQL injections. A correct code would be

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE password SET password = ? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute([password_hash($password), $id])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I missed the PASSWORD_DEFAULT in my password hash.
If I did something wrong leave a reaction, I would apprechiate that.

```
if(isset($_POST['update_password'])){
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];  
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password']; 

if(strlen($password) >= 8){
    if($password == $confirm_password){

        $new_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE forum_inhoud SET password = :new_password 
        WHERE id=:id");
        $stmt->execute([
            ':new_password' => $new_password,
            ':id' => $id
        ]);

        $_SESSION['success'] = 'Wachtwoord is bijgewerkt!';
        header('Location: ../../profile.php');
        exit(0);
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['failed'] = 'Er is iets misgegaan!';
    header('Location: ../../profile.php');
    exit(0);
}   
}
```